# Checking for NPE during batch run

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, spring-batch

I have a batch job which processes a huge amount of data. The job basically gets the data from a source database and make a web service call and then writes the data into target database. 
Today I faced "NPE" where I check the XML for the 'success' response. I check one of the nodes in order to determine whether the response is success or failure. 
I can have a try and catch block but I need to know if this is the correct and efficient approach.

Code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource source = new InputSource();
        source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));
        Document document = builder.parse(source);

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(DCDirectProcessorConstants.Tag_Response_getValue);
        Node node = nodeList.item( 0 ).getAttributes().getNamedItem(DCDirectProcessorConstants.Tag_Response_Status);

`Node node = nodeList.item( 0 ).getAttributes().getNamedItem(DCDirectProcessorConstants.Tag_Response_Status);` line throws NPE.
```

Stack trace

`java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mercuryinsurance.r3.util.MigrationExecutorThread.run(MigrationExecutorThrea .java:96) [migration.jar:?] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_66] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_66] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]`

So in that line I am just checking if the value of the tag is 'success' not sure if it's a good approach to have a try and catch block to handle NPE. Please advice

Thanks

Comment: `nodeList.item( 0 )` assumes there is an item in the list. Probably this what causes the NPE. I would be more defensive here and check if the list is not empty before getting an element from it. This probably would work without a try/catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a try catch block if you wish, but it may be cleaner and more efficient to just check if the parent object is null before calling any methods on it, i.e.

```
if (null != document) {
    NodeList nodelist = document...
}
```

You may want to wrap this entire thing in a try catch, however, because these methods may throw other exceptions than NPEs in certain circumstances.

Comment: Makes sense. And I don't see a loft of this exception during the batch job. Today it happened when the job just started.